# How to check permission on fragment using mvvm in andorid

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using kotlin with MVVM. I want to check multiple permission in fragment. I have used bellow code. It does not show permsion. But I off the permission, it show not show.here is my code..

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
private val PermissionsRequestCode = 123

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    if (activity?.let {
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                it,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        }
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (activity?.let {
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    it,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            }!!) {


        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity!!,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                PermissionsRequestCode)

        }
    } else {
        // Permission has already been granted
        Log.e("granted--","granted")
    }
  }
 }
```

Please help how properly handle the permission in kotiln fragment using mvvm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fragments have `requestPermissions()` and `onRequestPermissionsResult()` methods for requesting permissions and receiving the results of permission request.

You are using following method to request permissions, which is not correct

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity!!,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                PermissionsRequestCode)
```

Instead you should use the following

```
 requestPermissions(
        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 
        PermissionsRequestCode);
```

You should also adjust the placement of some of your conditions, I fixed some issues

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private val permissionsRequestCode = 123

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        activity?.let{
            when{
                permissionGranted() -> Log.e("granted--","granted")
                shouldShowRationale() -> {}// Show the rationale UI and then request permission
                else -> requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                    permissionsRequestCode)
            }
        }
    }

    // this is called when user closes the permission request dialog
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == permissionsRequestCode) {
            if (permissions[0]  == Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE &&
                grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted, do your work
            }
        }
    }

    private fun shouldShowRationale() = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
        activity!!,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

    private fun permissionGranted() = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            activity!!,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}
```